# Can't connect Cloud Foundry App (Node Red) to Watson Assistant

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, ibm-watson

first of all im new here and i dont have big knowledges of Programming or Watson Assistant.
I am just trying to test the opportunities of Watson cause i want to create a Chatbot for my Company.

So i followed the instructions of this Site: 
https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/artificial-intelligence/tutorials/integrate-coversation-service-with-telegram-using-node-red/
but every time i try to make a connection to my NodeRed App it says "Failed to get the service plan a7c3614c-c75f-4c45-85e4-0626492539d3".

I am thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

The archived tutorial you link to makes use of the Conversation node, which has long been deleted and replaced with Assistant and Assistant V2. You should be using one of those nodes, but the configuration you use will be different depending on which node you are using.

Assistant required a `Workspace ID` and Assistant V2 requires an `Assistant ID`. They are different.